# How to read more then 4096 symbols from terminal in clojure/java?

Tags: java, clojure

This code takes 2500 numbers from one line in clojure.

```
(import 'java.util.Scanner)
  (let [s (new Scanner *in*)]
    (for [i (range 2500)] (.nextInt s)))
```

But clojure takes only 4096 symbols.

I tried change scanner to buffer, but it doesn't work.

```
(import 'java.io.BufferReader)
(def r (new BufferedReader *in*))
(.read r)
```

It takes only 4096 symbols.

How to read more than 4096 symbols from on line from STDIN?

Comment: On windows&java, stdin doesn't ever give you characters until you hit "enter", it only feeds you a line at a time.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: This discussion might help: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/cVRfHcrMxc0/IgDRJIxDAwAJ

Comment: No, I uses linux. But, i don't think that it is problem.

Comment: If you write the data to a file, then read the file, does that work OK?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, here are some other answers that may help:

- [what is the max number of characters 'read' command can take in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749955/what-is-the-max-number-of-characters-read-command-can-take-in-one-line)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument